# Document Classification with scikit-learn: most efficient way to get the words (token) that impacted more on the classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, document-classification

I have built a document binomial classifier using a *tf-idf* representation of a training set of documents and applying Logistic Regression to it:

```
lr_tfidf = Pipeline([('vect', tfidf),('clf', LogisticRegression(random_state=0))])

lr_tfidf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I have saved the model in pickle format and used it to classify new documents, getting as a result the probability the document is in class A and the probability the model is in class B.

```
text_model = pickle.load(open('text_model.pkl', 'rb'))
results = text_model.predict_proba(new_document)
```

Which is the best way to also get the words (or, in general, the tokens) that impacted more in the classification? I would expect to get:

- The N tokens contained in the document which had the *higher* coefficient as a feature in the Logistic Regression model
- The N tokens contained in the document which had the *lower* coefficient as a feature in the Logistic Regression model

I am using sklearn v 0.19

Comment: You can access the `tfidf` inside the pipeline and get the words which are used as features. Then get the `coef_` from the `clf` and map the words from to those coefficients.

Comment: Thanks @VivekKumar . If I am not wrong, in that way I get the the features/coeff of the model, what I want to get, instead, is, for a new document, the features (words) that impacted more on the choice (which of course depend on the features/coeff of the model). Can you provide efficient code to get this result?

Comment: The features that are important or not are decided during training time. At testing or predicting only that learnt knowledge is used.

Comment: Sure, but the documents to classify will contain just a subset of the words used as features. My question is simple: what is the most efficient way to get the words that impacted more on the classification of a given (not belonging to the training set) document? I can think about the intersection of the feature set and the set of tokens that describe the document, considering just top and bottom features, the but maybe there are better ways. Can you provide code?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you just want to look at the parameters and sort the according to the coefficient value.
With .get_params() function, you can get the coefficients. You can argsort it and select the top N, bot N.

Comment: Can you provide code? As far as I know, get_params provides the parameters of the model, which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution on GitHub to print the most important features obtained from a classifier within a pipeline:

https://gist.github.com/bbengfort/044682e76def583a12e6c09209c664a1

You want to use `show_most_informative_features` function in their script. I used it and it works fine.

Here is a copy-paste of the Github poster's code:

```
def show_most_informative_features(model, text=None, n=20):

"""

Accepts a Pipeline with a classifer and a TfidfVectorizer and computes

the n most informative features of the model. If text is given, then will

compute the most informative features for classifying that text.



Note that this function will only work on linear models with coefs_

"""

# Extract the vectorizer and the classifier from the pipeline

vectorizer = model.named_steps['vectorizer']

classifier = model.named_steps['classifier']



# Check to make sure that we can perform this computation

if not hasattr(classifier, 'coef_'):

    raise TypeError(

        "Cannot compute most informative features on {} model.".format(

            classifier.__class__.__name__

        )

    )



if text is not None:

    # Compute the coefficients for the text

    tvec = model.transform([text]).toarray()

else:

    # Otherwise simply use the coefficients

    tvec = classifier.coef_



# Zip the feature names with the coefs and sort

coefs = sorted(

    zip(tvec[0], vectorizer.get_feature_names()),

    key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True

)



topn  = zip(coefs[:n], coefs[:-(n+1):-1])



# Create the output string to return

output = []



# If text, add the predicted value to the output.

if text is not None:

    output.append("\"{}\"".format(text))

    output.append("Classified as: {}".format(model.predict([text])))

    output.append("")



# Create two columns with most negative and most positive features.

for (cp, fnp), (cn, fnn) in topn:

    output.append(

        "{:0.4f}{: >15}    {:0.4f}{: >15}".format(cp, fnp, cn, fnn)

    )



return "\n".join(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code: print (show_most_informative_features(text_model, 'test content test content .... ')) but I get AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'transform'

Comment: The error occurs because the transform function is not available for logistic regression. I made a modified version of the function that works with any classifier model, including logreg. See my next post...

Comment: Thanks, I tried your function but I think it doesn't work as expected, see my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of the `show_most_informative_features` function that works with any classifier:

```
def show_most_informative_features(model, vectorizer=None, text=None, n=20):
# Extract the vectorizer and the classifier from the pipeline
if vectorizer is None:
    vectorizer = model.named_steps['vectorizer']
else:
    vectorizer.fit_transform([text])

classifier = model.named_steps['classifier']
feat_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# Check to make sure that we can perform this computation
if not hasattr(classifier, 'coef_'):
    raise TypeError(
        "Cannot compute most informative features on {}.".format(
            classifier.__class__.__name__
        )
    )    

# Otherwise simply use the coefficients
tvec = classifier.coef_

# Zip the feature names with the coefs and sort   
coefs = sorted(
    zip(tvec[0], feat_names),
    key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True
)

# Get the top n and bottom n coef, name pairs
topn  = zip(coefs[:n], coefs[:-(n+1):-1])

# Create the output string to return
output = []

# If text, add the predicted value to the output.
if text is not None:
    output.append("\"{}\"".format(text))
    output.append(
        "Classified as: {}".format(model.predict([text]))
    )
    output.append("")

# Create two columns with most negative and most positive features.
for (cp, fnp), (cn, fnn) in topn:
    output.append(
        "{:0.4f}{: >15}    {:0.4f}{: >15}".format(
            cp, fnp, cn, fnn
        )
    )

return "\n".join(output)
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
show_most_informative_features(model,vectorizer, "your text")
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems it doesn't work as expected; if I want to use the vectorizer in the model I guess I have to pass None to the function, instead of vectorized, am I right? But then I think at the beginning of the function a vectorizer.fit_transform([text]) is missing ... and if I add it I get ValueError: X has 474 features per sample; expecting 2795333.

Comment: I think your code contains an error: if I pass the vectorizer, feature_names only contains the features of the text but coefs contains all the coefficient in the model, can you check it? I guess you first have to get, from coefs, the coefficients correspondent to the features of the text passed.